# How to turn off select before SaveAll()?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to turn off the select before saveAll() in a spring boot application with Hibernate and Jpa to boost performance with high number of records.

I've found a method with JPQL with good performance (delete + save of 10k records in 30s), but i'd like to stay with hibernate and jpa.

My expectations are that when i run my code written in java, i have to deleteAll the record of a table, then saveAll records from another one. When i do that in classic way (deleteAll(), findAll() and then saveAll()), i got low performance during the saveAll() because it does a select of all records got on the list before saving them.

I'd like to avoid the code to execute all selects before saving the records. Is that possibile without using EntityManager or EntityManagerFactory?

Comment: Try with JPA only (not spring data jpa) and use Sets if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Code two native query: DELETE and INSERT SELECT using the @Query annotation on your repository class.

It's the best way to resolve these issues. If you only has to copy records from a table to another, it's no sense use jpa and loading thousands of objects. Using findAll could throw out of memory errors.